# VS Code had a problem in running the code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I tried to run a python program in VS Code. But my program didn't run. The terminal opened and a weird arrow was there in the terminal. This is the screenshot of that.
[image]

This is the weird arrow and the program is not running. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try ```ctrl+z``` then run the code

Comment: btw you are in the terminal ,go to output

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the arrows are included in the default python IDE means that VScode ran the command to execute your code. Give your pc a restart. Now, let us check if python is working or not or VS code is having some trouble. Type the following command in cmd to execute the code-

```
python "$PATH"
```

**Rember to replace $PATH to the path of the file i.e where your file is stored.** *For eg. I've my python files stored in D drive in a python folder*, so I'll use-

```
python "D:\Python\Hello.py"
```

If this works, python is working fine and if not, try reinstalling python and check the box which says *Add python to Path or Environment variables*. Then open VS code try to run the program again. But click the button only once and be patient because clicking it multiple times causes execute the same command again and cause a problem. It's my personal experience. Wait 5 minutes. Not works. Don't worry, there's a problem with the **run extension** you are using. I'll recommend the **Code runner** by **Jun han**. I personally use it. Type this in the extension search box-

> formulahendry.code-runner

Install it and then try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There was a problem in the default Python Extension that I had installed in vs code. I am now using the Code Runner extension that you suggested and it is working fine!

Comment: @OjesJain If you find my answer helpful so mark it correct so that other people facing the same issue get their problem resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the terminal, and retry. If not work, restart the VSCode.